# Mongoose not returns the error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Try to update a document in mongodb through mongoose:

```
Company.update({"_id": objectId }, {$set: replaceObject }, function(err, object, affected)
```

My models field

```
name: {
        type: String,
        unique: false,
        required: true
    },
```

Name is required! Update works well, but when I try to imitate the error by passing empty string in the name field - there are no errors passing in callback. On save this trick works, why update not working properly? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the documentation **tells you** this:

> http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update

Update is a pass through for a **server** side operation and as stated in the document you will loose

- defaults
- setters
- validators
- middleware

You get the benefits of the server operation, but you **need** to control the logic like this yourself.

Comment: thanks, that kindly odd from ruby on rails active record logic